# Redondear esquinas de un textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

hoy he estado manejando algunos componentes del Windows Form para un proyecto escolar, ya tengo una gran parte de el avanzado y por ello trato de manejar todo en una clase aislada antes de implementar, pero tengo unos problemas con algo que tal vez sea muy sencillo o no.
Mi duda es ¿como puedo hacer que las esquinas de un text box sea circulares? intente adaptar un codigo de por la red pero no esta funcionando mucho que digamos, pues solo las esquinas superiores son redondas más las de abajo no.
Anexo el codigo de la clase donde saco el text box:

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
    int nLeftRect,
    int nTopRect, 
    int nRightRect, 
    int nBottomRect, 
    int nWidthEllipse,
    int nHeightEllipse
    );

    public TextBox addNewTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        txt.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(20, 0, 150, 0, 15, 15));
        return txt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes asegurarte de pasar las coordenadas correctamente al metodo `CreateRoundRectRgn (int x1,  int y1,  int x2,  int y2,  int w,  int h)`

- `x1` corresponde a la coordenada en X de la punta superior izquierda
  del control.
- `y1` corresponde la coordenada en Y de la punta superior izquierda
  del control
- `x2` corresponde a la coordenada en X de la punta inferior derecha
- `y2` corresponde a la coordenada en Y de la punta inferior derecha
- `w` corresponde al acnho que va a tener la elipse.
- `h` corresponde al alto de la elipse usada para redondear las
  esquinas.

Normalmente en `x2` y `y2` debe ir el ancho y el alto del control respectivamente. y en `x1` y `y1` intenta probando con valores diferentes a 0 como por ejemplo 2 y 3 respecitvamente. Puedes probrar con el siguiente código.

```
txt.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 3, txt.Width, txt.Height, 15, 15));
```

**Asegurate que `txt.Width` y `txt.Height` tengan un valor mayor que 0.**

Comment: En efecto, el problema venia de las coordenas, muchas gracias!

Comment: @ManuelTorres De nada, No olvides marcar la respuesta como solución, si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que en la BorderStyle se deje FixedSingle, se adapta mucho mejor. 
Ademas hay que agregar primero la librería

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Lo que me funcionó a mi fue esto,queda ya como método al que nomás se le pasa en TextBox,por si quieren agregarlo a alguna librería para proyectos futuros, espero sirva.

```
 public TextBox RedondearText(TextBox txt)
    {

        txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        txt.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(1, 1, txt.Width, txt.Height, 6, 6));           
        return txt;
    }
```